# Can't change the Sprite of a spawned game object (Client only)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, unity3d-unet

I am attempting to instantiate, spawn, then assign a sprite to a custom `GameObject` in Unity3D. The objects are a generic `CardContainer` that call a `SetCard` method to give it its custom stats. Calling `SetCard` also assigns the `CardContainer` its Sprite.

My problem is that, whenever I change the `SpriteRenderer.sprite` of a spawned `GameObject`, the sprite change does not take affect on the client instance.

It also seems to not reflect if I've made any changes to the `Sprite` *before* I spawn the object. Is this possible to change the sprite, and how can I do it?

I have set up a few small poc tests, but nothing has worked so far. Here they are:

```
//cardContainerTesting
Vector3 testingContainerCoords= new 
Vector3(0, 1, -1);
GameObject testingCardObjectInstance = Instantiate(testingCardCOntainerGameObject, testingContainerCoords, Quaternion.identity); 
NetworkServer.Spawn(testingCardObjectInstance);
SpriteRenderer objectSprite = testingCardObjectInstance.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
objectSprite.sprite = testingSprite1;


//GenericGameObjectExampleTesting
Vector3 origin = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
GameObject instantiatedPrefab = Instantiate(myPrefabExample, origin, Quaternion.identity);
NetworkServer.Spawn(instantiatedPrefab);
SpriteRenderer exampleSpriteRenderer = instantiatedPrefab.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
exampleSpriteRenderer.sprite = testingSprite2;
```

Comment: Do you know the possible sprites beforehand so you can e.g. store them in a list or dictionary?

Comment: I have all my sprites stored in my "SpriteCollection" dictionary and they can be gathered from and CardContainer through my "SetCard" function.  It was working great until I tried multiplayer. I ran out of characters on my other comment but I just want to thank you a bunch. Yours post was really thorough and must have taken a while. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is quite tricky and depends on your case.

The best-case would be that beforehand you know which Sprites are available and store them e.g. in a `List<Sprite>` .. then you can simply tell the clients which sprite to use by setting e.g. a `[SyncVar]` on the spawned object. Something like

```
// on the spawned object
public class SpriteController : NetworkBehaviour
{
    // Also good if you reference this already in the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    // Configured via the Inspector befrorehand
    public List<Sprite> Sprites;

    // Whenever this is changed on the Server
    // the change is automatically submitted to all clients
    // by using the "hook" it calls the OnSpriteIndexChanged and passes
    // the new value in as parameter
    [SyncVar(hook = nameof(OnSpriteIndexChanged))] public int SpriteIndex;

    // Will be called everytime the index is changed on the server
    [ClientCallback]
    private void OnSpriteIndexChanged(int newIndex)
    {
        // First when using a hook you have to explicitly apply the changed value at some point
        SpriteIndex = newIndex;

        if (!spriteRenderer) spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        spriteRenderer.sprite = Sprites[SpriteIndex];
    }
}
```

and then do e.g.

```
// If you make this of type SpriteController the Inspector automatically
// references the correct component and you can get rid of the GetComponent call later
public SpriteController testingCardCOntainerGameObject;

var testingCardObjectInstance = Instantiate(testingCardCOntainerGameObject, testingContainerCoords, Quaternion.identity); 

// for testing use 1 since 0 is the default for int ;)
testingCardObjectInstance.SpriteIndex = 1;

NetworkServer.Spawn(testingCardObjectInstance);
```

Now the target sprite object initializes itself with the correct sprite.

Additionally using the `hook` now it is actually changed **every time** the index is changed **on the server**. So now you can even switch the Sprite at runtime dynamically by simply assigning a new index:

```
private void Update()
{
    if(!isServer || !Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.ArrowUp)) return;

    SpriteIndex = (SpriteIndex + 1) % Sprites.Count;
}
```

[image]

---

An alternative would maybe consist in transmitting the actual `Texture2D` data. This is a bit tricky since the allowed parameters/data types passed via UNet are very limited

```
// the sprite we will transfer
public Sprite targetSprite;

// the prefab to spawn
// directly use the component type here so we get rid of one GetComponent call
public SpriteRenderer examplePRefab;

[Command]
public void Cmd_Spawn()
{
    // ON SERVER

    var obj = Instantiate(examplePRefab);
    // on the server set the sprite right away
    obj.sprite = targetSprite;

    // spawn (sprite will not be set yet)
    NetworkServer.Spawn(obj.gameObject);

    // tell clients to set the sprite and pass required data
    Rpc_AfterSpawn(obj.gameObject, targetSprite.texture.EncodeToPNG(), new SpriteInfo(targetSprite));
}

[Serializable]
private struct SpriteInfo
{
    public Rect rect;
    public Vector2 pivot;

    public SpriteInfo(Sprite sprite)
    {
        rect = sprite.rect;
        pivot = sprite.pivot;
    }
}

[ClientRpc]
private void Rpc_AfterSpawn(GameObject targetObject, byte[] textureData, SpriteInfo spriteInfo)
{
    // ON CLIENTS

    // the initial width and height don't matter
    // they will be overwritten by load
    // also the texture format will automatically be RGB24 for jpg data
    // and RGBA32 for png
    var texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    //  load the byte[] into the texture
    texture.LoadImage(textureData);
    var newSprite = Sprite.Create(texture, spriteInfo.rect, spriteInfo.pivot);

    // finally set the sprite on all clients
    targetObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = newSprite;
}
```

[image]

**Note however**:

- This is also very limited since UNet only allows a NetworkBuffer of afaik 64kb so any bigger image/texture (+ the rest of data!) will not be possible to transmit on this way and it would get more complex.

  Also note in this regard that `EncideToXY` often results in a [bigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53216075/png-file-grows-in-unity-after-applying-downloaded-texture-and-convert-back-to-pn) data size than the original image.
- I'm also not sure right now if the execution order of `Spawn` and `Rpc_AfterSpawn` will be reliable over the network. It might happen that `Rpc_AfterSpawn` reaches the clients before the `Spawn` is actually done.

Comment: Thank you! I've been stuck for an embarrassingly long time on this issue. I've been unsuccessfully trying to apply your instructions today. I have your code pasted into my project verbatim. I am now getting *a* sprite to appear for my client, but not the correct one. The sprite appearing is the 0'th item on my "Sprites" list rather than the first, or any other index I input. Its finding the correct sprite in the host. Any ideas? To me it seems like the SpriteIndex is not being shared properly. I added your start function code to the update function to make sure it runs and still nothing.

Comment: Hey I'm sorry .. not sure anymore since UNet was quite a while ago ... I was pretty sure that it works using `Start` and afaik the `[SyncVar]` should be syncronized after Spawn before `Start` is called. It also worked for me .. but maybe it was a runtime "bug" and only worked for me since I'm testing within the same PC. However, I updated the code to instead use a `hook` and `[ClientCallback]` for the synced index so now you can even change the index afterwards (on the Server) and the sprite will be exchanged dynamically on all clients (and the server ofcourse ;) )

Comment: Hey man, I appreciate all you help here. I've been working on it for a while with absolutely no luck. Even when I manually change values in the inspector I cannot get my SyncVars to actually sync. No idea what the problem is. My host and client appear to be connected. I've even put together a simple poc project with just your code in it and I'm getting the same result. Im gonna reinstall a new version of Unity in case this is some crazy bug. Your answer appears to be correct so Im gonna mark it that way. Thanks a bunch for all you help.

Comment: @john_shreds the **only** working way is by changing the value on the server side **via code**. Changing it via the inspector doesn't trigger the `SyncVar`! Therefore for the fist demo I used `private void Update(){if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) { SpriteIndex = (SpriteIndex + 1) % Sprites.Count; } }` in order to increase it by script

Comment: Wow I feel really dumb, I thought I had tried that earlier but I just tried it again and it worked. Only in my poc (not my real project) but this should still serve as an example to work from. I swear I tried this method first before using the inspector manually but who knows. I am a little confused by the gif you posted though. I thought I saw you editing values in the host inspector and seeing the client synchvars change as a result.

Comment: No worries, unfortunately this is not well documented and I also always expect it to work using the Inspector for test it